# Bad substitution error in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax-error

I have tried a lot but couldn't get the solution out of it. I have a simple script:

```
#! /bin/sh
o="12345"
a=o
b=${!a}
echo ${a}
echo ${b}
```

When executed like

```
$ . scp.sh
```

it produces the correct output with no errors, but when executed like:

```
$ ./scp.sh
```

it produces

> ./scp.sh: 4: ./scp.sh: Bad substitution

Any ideas why this is happening.

---

I was suggested to use bash mode and it works fine. But when I execute this same script through Python (changing the script header to bash), I am getting the same error.

I'm calling it from Python as:

```
import os
os.system(". ./scp.sh")
```

Comment: Can you show the line used in python script to execute this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

instead of

```
#! /bin/sh
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. But if I execute this same script through python (changing to bash mode), I get the same error. I am editing the question now. It would be more feasible.

Comment: from python instead of doing os.system("scp.sh") try doing os.system("bash scp.sh") and see if it helps

Comment: Even if I only specify os.system("./scp.sh") it works. I dont understand that why os.system(". ./scp.sh") is not working. Though $SHELL in my environment is /bin/shell so it should use bash instead of sh and I have also changed the script header to bash now.

Comment: most probably ". ./scp.sh" is spawning the user's default shell (which I bet is "sh" in your case) and running ". ./scp.sh" in that shell, whereas ".scp.sh" is not doing that, try running your process unders strace and see what is happening

Comment: Many languages specifically use "/bin/sh" as the shell for the "system()" command. I bet python does this (check the documentation). This probably works: `system("./scp.sh")` after you switch the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this error is that two different shells are used in these cases.

`$ . scp.sh` command will use the current shell (`bash`) to execute the script (without forking a sub shell).

`$ ./scp.sh` command will use the shell specified in that hashbang line of your script. And in your case, it's either `sh` or `dash`.

The easiest way out of it is replacing the first line with `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever path `bash` is in).